# Counter example of convergence in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

I have just shown that in $L^p([a,b])$ for $p=1,2$, if we have $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $\left \|  f_n\right \|_p\rightarrow \left \|  f\right \|_p$, then there is convergence in $L^p$:
$$\left \| f_n -f \right \|_p\rightarrow0$$
I was wondering if this can be generalized for other $L^p$ spaces, and I am particularly concerned about $L^{\infty}([a,b])$. My intuition is that it shouldn't, but I am struggling to find a counterexample in $L^{\infty}([a,b])$, which should in principle be the easist space to disprove it.

My question therefore is, is there any example of a sequence $\{f_n\}\in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ and $f\in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere and $\left \|  f_n\right \|_{\infty}\rightarrow \left \|  f\right \|_{\infty}$, but $\{f_n\}$ does not converge to $f$ in  $L^{\infty}([a,b])$ (that is, with the supremum norm)?

Comment: Which counterexample did you use for the other $L^p$?

Comment: My hint would be to pick the $f_n$ continuous and the $f$ discontinuous, then you know that the convergence is not uniform (continuity would be preserved under uniform convergence).

Comment: I did not use any counterexample for the other $L^p$, I knew it to be true for p=1,2 and tried to break it, so I began tinkering with $L^{\infty}$ , because it seemed to me it would be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take
$$f_n(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x^n &\text{ if } x\in[0,1]
\\
1&\text{ if } x\in[1,2].
\end{array}\right.
$$
It converges to $f = \mathbb{1}_{[1,2]}$ almost everywhere, and $\|f_n\|_{L^\infty} = \|f\|_{L^\infty} = 1$, but $\|f_n-f\|_{L^\infty} = 1$, so it does not converges in $L^\infty$.